# Installation error - Background Geoprocessing (64bit) - ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, installation, background-geoprocessing

I'm running ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1 (Advanced) (`ArcGIS_Desktop_1071_fr_169511.exe`). When I try to install Background GP (`ArcGIS_Desktop_BackgroundGP_107_167531.exe`) downloaded from our own company's site (and not ESRI site) I recieve an error that `BP 10.7 requires ArcGIS 10.7`.

My ArcGIS is 10.7. Already uninstalled and reinstalled ArcGIS. Before this version I was using 10.5 with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention both 10.7.1 and 10.7. You need to match the versions. Based on the file names you mention, it sounds like you have **ArcMap 10.7.1** and **Background GP 10.7**.

You'll need to get **Background GP 10.7.1** to install with your current 10.7.1 version of ArcMap.

Comment: Oh, rookie mistake. Thanks. Thought 10.7 should work with all 10.7s.

Comment: No problem - The `.1` version is more of a full release than it is a service pack. Generally (although not advised) software is allowed to be out of sync if its just a patch, but full releases need to match.

Comment: Thanks for the info.