# ArcGIS Background Geoprocessing Install Error

Tags: arcmap, background-geoprocessing

I'm trying to install 64-bit Background Geoprocessing for ArcMap 10.8 using the 10.8 install from ESRI. I'm running ArcMap 10.8.1 but I receive this error when trying to install. It's happened on two machines running 10.8.1. Has anyone had this before and knows a solution?

[image: Error]

Comment: You need to use Background Geoprocessing **10.8.1** with ArcMap **10.8.1**.

Comment: This is exactly the same question as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351408/installation-error-background-geoprocessing-64bit-arcgis-desktop-10-7-1, just changing the "7" to an "8"